# Sort a list by multiple fields

Tags: c#, list, sorting, c#-2.0

I have problem where sort one list with more one field.

necessary to organize two courses simultaneously by color first and then the banana position.

Names of entities are only for example.

```
 private List<Banana> OrderProduct(List<Banana> list)
    {
        list.Sort(
            delegate(Banana b1, Banana b2)
            {
                return b1.Green.CompareTo(b2.Banana) && b1.Position.CompareTo(b2.Position);
            });
        return lista;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
bananas.Sort(
    delegate(Banana b1, Banana b2)
    {          
        int res = b1.Color.CompareTo(b2.Color);
        return res != 0 ? res : b1.Position.CompareTo(b2.Position);
    });
```